# Гарантированная отчистка памяти

Tags: rust

Еслть ли возможность гарантированно отчищать использованные переменные? Например ключи ЭЦП. Нужно быть уверенным, что ничего в памяти не останется (чтобы не было как с memset в Си).

Comment: Есть несколько библитек для этого, но все они используют один и тот же механизм.
https://github.com/iqlusioninc/crates/blob/develop/zeroize/src/lib.rs#L254